# Google map fitBounds not working as expected

Tags: google-maps

I am trying to fitBounds within a country. I have following:

```
 global.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

        });

        var southWest = new google.maps.LatLng(55.869295662409286, 10.20150283108661);
        var northEast = new google.maps.LatLng(58.02569542932735, 15.9528456045241);
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);
        global.map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

When the map is initialized it has following data:

NorthEast: { "lat": 59.05764174257586, "lng": 18.82851699124285 }

SouthWest: { "lat": 54.74380264275119, "lng": 7.32583144436785 }

I would expect that bounds would have data given in fitBounds coordinates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `fitBounds` method will make sure the supplied coordinates are visible within the bounds of the viewport, so there will usually be a buffer around them. To get rid of it you would need to adjust your supplied bounds inward by the amount of the buffer. I don't know if this buffer is a fixed size.

The viewport bounds will also be set to suit the viewport dimensions, which may differ from the dimensions of a theoretical box using your supplied `LatLngBounds` as two corners. e.g. Your viewport might be 800x600, but your `LatLngBounds` might describe a shape closer to 600x600 at the suitable zoom level.

Set the padding parameter in the fitBounds method to zero to eliminate padding:

`global.map.fitBounds(bounds, 0);`

Comment: Thanks. What is the approach then to set exact bounds?

Comment: The fitBounds method accepts a padding parameter, you could try setting that to zero: `global.map.fitBounds(bounds, 0);` If that doesn't work the alternative is trial and error, reducing the supplied bounds to get a fit over the bounds you actually want.